# How to bridge ERC-20 EFI tokens to Efinity parachain address using Enjin wallet?

Tags: erc-20, wallets, bridge

I have been holding some EFI tokens in my Ethereum wallet and would like to transfer them to my Efinity parachain address. I am using the Enjin wallet on my Android device and was wondering if there is a way to bridge these tokens to my Efinity address using this wallet.